# Parsing Unicode JSON object in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, regex, unicode, json

I'm trying to parse text from tweets in PHP 5.3, but I have a problem with parsing user mentions, hashtags and links which contain Unicode characters.

First I fetch tweets and store it to txt file:

```
$tweets_file = createFile('cache/'.$twitteruser.'-tweets.txt', json_encode($tweets));
```

After that, in my text file I can see bunch of Unicode characters (e.g. `Landsli\u00f0sma\u00f0ur`).

When I try to display all the tweets I do it like this:

```
function twitterify($text) {
  $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#u", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $text);
  $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#u", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $text);
  $text = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/u", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $text);
  $text = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/u", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $text);
  return $text;
}

$tweets_file = file_get_contents('cache/'.$queried_user.'-tweets.txt');
$tweets = json_decode($tweets_file);
foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
  echo twitterify($tweet->text);
  // do other stuff...
}
```

Everything works fine here until there is a Unicode character in hashtag for example. My `preg_replace` stops at that character and a hashtag like `#rafhlaða` renders to `<a href="#">#rafhla</a>ða`.

What can I do to properly render out text with Unicode characters in it?

Comment: plz, post the contents of the file into pastebin and add the link to question

Comment: Contents of the file is here http://pastebin.com/kzXqwwVT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error. I took JSON data from pastebin and modified it to the simplest case:

```
[{"text":"#rafhla\u00f0a"}]
```

So, the text is just 1 word: rafhlaða

Then ran the following script:

```
<?php
function twitterify($ret) {
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#u", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#u", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/u", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/u", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $ret);
    return $ret;
}


$tweets_file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$tweets = json_decode($tweets_file);
foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
    print $tweet->text;
    print "\n";
    echo twitterify($tweet->text);
    exit;
}
```

It printed:

```
#rafhlaða
<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=rafhlaða" target="_blank">#rafhlaða</a>
```

Which contradicts to your statement:

```
#rafhlaða renders to <a href="#">#rafhla</a>ða
```

### update

```
<?php
function twitterify($ret) {
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/@(.+?)(?=\s|$)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/#(.+?)(?=\s|$)/", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $ret);
    return $ret;
}


$tweet = '[{"text":"#rafhla\u00f0a #rafhla\u00f0a"}]';
$tweet = json_decode($tweet);
print $tweet[0]->text;
print "\n";
echo twitterify($tweet[0]->text);
```

prints:

`#rafhlaða #rafhlaða`

`<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=rafhlaða" target="_blank">#rafhlaða</a> <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=rafhlaða" target="_blank">#rafhlaða</a>`

Comment: Well, this is odd... I triple checked your snippet with mine but I still have this problem =/

Comment: @errata Maybe, something is different in Unicode support in our php interpreters? Mine is PHP 5.4.7 (cli) (built: Sep 14 2012 14:44:02) Running on Linux Slackware 14.0

Comment: I even tried to reproduce your case. Still got the same problem... My PHP is v5.3.15 on Mac OS X 10.8.4.

Comment: @errata Here I tried to reproduce online, but it works successfully http://ideone.com/M1umyK

Comment: @errata I found the cause: "This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32" http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Just tried on some Linux server with PHP v5.2.17, same problem. Tried on different server - Windows with PHP v5.2.14, works good =( Is there any way to make it work properly on *any* server?

Comment: I don't understand, it says that `u` is available from 4.1 or 4.2 but still I am trying on different 5.X versions.

Comment: @errata The problem is with the word boundary. It thinks, that non-ascii character is a word boundary. I updated my answer to search up to space of end of line. Plz, try it.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a million for your effort =)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your script (and leave out the preg_replace):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8');
```

Solution two :

```
$tweets_file = file_get_contents('cache/'.$queried_user.'-tweets.txt', FILE_TEXT);
```

Comment: Hm, but then my page does not render as HTML content but as plain text? Like I'm looking at the source of my file.

Comment: Then the question is, why are you storing JSON data in a txt file (cache/'.$queried_user.'-tweets.txt) and not a .json file?

Comment: I tried to save .json file and also tried to add FILE_TEXT when reading txt file. Still the same problem =(